# How to get data from the clipboard in a node script?

Tags: javascript, clipboard

I'm trying to automate some tests for an app and i need to know the contents of the clipboard to confirm if the click on the "copy to clipboard" button actually worked.

P.S. Obviously I cant use the Browser Api as this is just a Javascript script. Ideally I'm looking for something like-

```js
let data = getClipboardData();
console.log(data);
```

I want the getbclipboarddata function.